# Do almost simple groups have determinant 1?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $ G $ be a (non-abelian) simple finite group. Then the image of a degree $ d $  representation $ \pi: A \to U_d $ always lies in $ SU_d $.

Indeed this is true even if $ G $ is quasisimple.

What if $ G $ is almost simple? It seems obvious that this would no longer be true. For a reducible representation this is easy to show. The natural permutation representation $ \pi: S_5 \to U_5 $ has half matrices $ det=-1 $ thus is not contained in $ SU_5 $.

It seems almost ridiculous to ask this because I think a counterexample should be obvious but I can't think of one:

What is an example of a faithful degree $ d $ irreducible representation $ \pi: G \to U_d $ of an almost simple finite group $ G $ whose image is not in $ SU_d $?

The obvious first place to look is the faithful irreps of $ S_5 $. These all map into $ O_4, O_5 $ or $ O_6 $. However it's not obvious to me whether or not these map into $ SO_4,SO_5,SO_6 $.

Comment: The element $(1,2)$ in  the standard $4$-dimensional deleted permutation module of $S_5$ maps to a matrix with three eigenvalues $1$ and one $-1$. That's an easy calculation. Morew generally you can usually find this information easily from the character of the representation.

Comment: @Derek Holt How do you find this information from the character?

Comment: The character value on $(1,2)$ is $2$, which tells you that the eigenvalues must be $1,1,1,-1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh that's really cool since its an involution the characteristic polynomial is $ \lambda^2-1 $ so eigenvalues must all be $ \pm 1 $ and since they sum to $ 2 $ your conclusion follows. I really like that! Do you want to put that as an answer? Otherwise I'll just post my edit as an answer and also recap your comment and credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Derek Holt given in the comments:

The conjugacy class of (1,2) in $ S_5 $ has character value $ 2 $. Since $ (1,2) $ is an involution all its eigenvalues are $ \pm 1 $. Since the four eigenvalues sum to $ 2 $  and are all $ \pm 1 $ they must be $ 1,1,1,-1 $ and thus the image of $ (1,2) $ in such a representation must have determinant $ -1 $, in other words it must be in $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $ not in $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $.

Here is a concrete example. The matrices $ F_1,F_2',F_3' $ in

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905212

generate a 4d irrep of $ A_5 $. Adding in the matrix $ CNOT=\overline{\zeta_8} F' $ (just $ F' $ from top of page 7 but without the phase)
$$
CNOT:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
generates a 4d irrep of $ S_5 $ where the det 1 subgroup is exactly $ A_5 $ and the rest of $ S_5 $ all has determinant $ -1 $.